# Biblatex won't compile with XeLaTeX and print bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, xetex, warnings, compiling

I have been testing out `biblatex` to get more control over the bibliography format that you get from BibTeX. Therefore I have been trying to get this to compile. The problem is that bibliography does not print but the citations do. Here is the current minimal working example of the document I am using to test out `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% clear any old style settings
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
%new settings
\lhead{\footnotesize {Sebastian Stephenson}}
\rhead{\footnotesize{2812193}}
\rfoot{{\thepage} of \pageref{LastPage}}
%for hardvard style citation (check with a person at tutorial to see if what is being complied is ok)
%\citestyle{agms}
% addfont Times New Roman
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{doublespacing}
    \title{The French New Wave}
    %to remove the date that is added when it gets complied
    \date{}
    \maketitle
    %Because the maketitle command has been used, it automatically
    %issues \thispagestyle{plain} which overrides the fancy headings for
    %this page.  Must now tell Latex to override this
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    The French New Wave represents a diverse...Two by Jean-Luc Godard: Á bout du shofflle(Breathless)\cite{godardfilmb}and Alphaville\cite{godardfilma} and one by Jacques Rivette called Céline et Julie vont en bateau (Céline and Julie Go Boating)\cite{rivettemovie}.



French New Wave would produce chain reactions around Europe\cite{newwavegen}. The work done during this period is important for medium of film.


    \end{doublespacing}
    % \newpage
    \defbibheading{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography% [nottype=video]
    % \defbibheading{Filmography}
    %   \printbibliography[type=video]
    \end{document}
```

The `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` is because this is coming up in the log but does not seem to change anything.

```
Package biblatex Warning: Data encoding is 'utf8'.
(biblatex)                Use backend=biber.

(./Essay.bbl

Package biblatex Warning: BibTeX reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'rivettesense':
(biblatex)                - Invalid format of field 'month'.


Package biblatex Warning: BibTeX reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'sensegodard':
(biblatex)                - Invalid format of field 'month'.


Package biblatex Warning: BibTeX reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'reviewgoboating':
(biblatex)                - Invalid format of field 'month'.


Package biblatex Warning: BibTeX reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'godardportrait':
(biblatex)                - Invalid format of field 'month'.


Package biblatex Warning: BibTeX reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'madmen':
(biblatex)                - Invalid format of field 'month'.

)
```

This is what they entry for `rivettesense` is like. I did change the entry types which would have been in misc in the working original to try out the new entries I could use as well. in the origianl bib file this would have been under `@misc`

```
@online{rivettesense,
author={Saul Austerlitz},
title={Jacques Rivette | Senses of Cinema},
month={January},
year={2003},
url={http://sensesofcinema.com/2003/great-directors/rivette/},
publisher={Senses of Cinema},
address={Melbourne},
note={[30/10/12]}
}
```

If you need any more information, please comment below.

Comment: Can you show the entry in the bib file corresponding to `rivettesense`?

Comment: While it may not cause the warnings at hand, it doesn't seem ideal to use XeLaTeX on the one hand (presumably because one wants to use  an unrestricted Umicode character set) and BibTeX on the other hand (which can't really deal with Unicode).

Comment: By the way, the correct original title of Godard's movie is "À bout de souffle"

Comment: Agh! egreg if only I knew! lockstep the reason I use xelatex is because I don't have to deal with embedding fonts in the document. I can use the system fonts on my Mac. I have not come across any characters that don't yet compile correctly with xelatex. I didn't know I was limited though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting section 2.2.2 of the manual:

> `month` field (integer)
>
> The publication month. This must be an integer, not an ordinal or a
>   string. Don’t say `month={January}` but `month={1}`. The bibliography
>   style converts this to a language dependent string or ordinal where
>   required.

The other warning is fairly straightforward: If the data encoding is `utf8`, one should use biber instead of BibTeX as backend. This is even more true if, as in your case, one uses XeLaTeX.

Comment: I have added backend=biber to the preamble but I am getting this error saying that it could not find control file "Essay.aux.bcf". What is there though is a "Essay.bcf". Any ideas? I am typing xelatex Essay.tex, then biber Essay.aux and then the error is generated

Comment: @sebey Remove all auxiliary files and compile again.

Comment: Not working I am afraid. Same effect. If it helps I am running biber 0.9.9

Comment: Perhaps you don't have an up-to-date TeX distribution and are missing biber?

Comment: I am updating the biber packages. I got it form Mac-TeX 2012. http://www.tug.org/mactex/. Hopefully that should fix the problem

Comment: Am now on biber 1.3 and still says "Cannot find control file 'Essay.aux.bcf'!- did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?" any ideas?

Comment: @sebey It seems your editor isn't configured correctly to compile with biber. Compiling *should* workf from the command line.

Comment: Hey I pasted the tex block into a new file and ran xelatex untitled.tex then biber untitled.aux and got the same error. (future reference: see revisions of this answer)

Comment: @sebey Omit the file extensions `.tex` and `.aux` and try again.

Comment: It seems to complie on biber this time but when I when then do the next two xelatex commands I get this "! Undefined control sequence.
l.21   \sortlist
                {entry}{}
? 
" 

is this intentional?

Comment: @sebey Check if your `biblatex` version is 2.3. If not, update.

Comment: its version 3.14

Comment: @sebey *This* is probably your TeX version. Add `\listfiles` at the very start of the example, compile as usual, then check the `.log` file for package versions.

Comment: opps! it's 1.7. Will update now

Comment: yep the example worked and the the test document is compiling but the bibliography is not printing on the screen. There are a lot of things that need to be updated. I guess I should updates all the packages that have updates?

Comment: @sebey You did use my example without any changes? And you did compile using XeLaTeX/biber/XeLaTeX/XeLaTeX from the command line?

Comment: the example hasn't been changed, neither the test document. Did you mean to implement you example into my test document?

Comment: @sebey No, I didn't mean that. Yes, updating everything is a good idea (unless you're on a deadline). But I can't figure out why my example works for me (see screenshot), but not for you.

Comment: @sebey Do you mean that only *your* document doesn't work for you? In that case, remove unnecessary packages/commands from your document (one step at a time) until it compiles. I can't be more specific.

Comment: the example does work for me but the document I am using (see MWE) does not work. I guess updating everything would help?

Comment: it was this line "\defbibheading{Bibliography}". The bibliography prints but I am now getting warnings saying "Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type 'video'.
(biblatex)                Using fallback driver on input line 14." 

3 of those errors have come up

Comment: @sebey That's only a warning. It means that you have `@video` entries, but this type is not supported by the `biblatex` standard styles. Check the entries if any data is missing. BTW, this is rather a new question, and I'd be glad if you accepted my answer to the present one.

Comment: yes that is true. Thank you so much. You have been great. Do you have any idea why "\defbibheading{Bibliography}" was the problem?

Comment: @sebey I noticed it now. The second argument of `\defbibheading` is missing -- see section 3.6.7 of the manual. And thanks for accepting!